# Gitlab ssh is enabled but no longer allows clone/push/etc

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I was able to push to GitLab via SSH until recently. We changed a number of configuration things so I'm having issues sorting out what the issue is. The biggest changes are I'm now on a VPN, the project changed owners, and IPs were restricted. I have a feeling it's something to do with the IP restrictions.

`ssh -T git@gitlab.com` prints `Welcome to GitLab, @myUsername!` **so the ssh connection is working**.

However if I attempt to clone, push, etc. it fails with various errors (added below) but ultimately says `Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists`.

I've tried various things (added below), primarily modifying the remote to use my username in various capacities based on other answers I found. None of them work. **I am able to push/clone via https**.

Is there an IP I need to allow or some other config in gitlab I need to set?

Some of the things I've tried:

`git remote add origin git@myUsername.gitlab.com:companyName/projectName.git`

`git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:companyName/projectName.git`

`git remote add origin myUsername@gitlab.com:companyName/projectName.git`

And their corresponding errors:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myUsername.gitlab.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

```
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

```
myUsername@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: "it fails with various errors" and "I've tried various things" is fairly unhelpful :(  SUGGESTION: Enable GitLab verbose logging: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html

Comment: You're right, I added the errors to my post. I'll try verbose logging ty.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Double-check your repository's configuration: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#testing-that-everything-is-set-up-correctly
- Configure your repository for HTTPS authentication https://forum.gitlab.com/t/could-not-read-from-remote-repository-from-gitlab-com/7508/2
- Enable GitLab verbose logging: docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html